# Give dynamic color to a ImageButton using svg resource as background

Tags: android, colors

I have a svg icon imported to android studio.

The svg is basically a heart with a hard coded color.

I wish to set the color of this heart dynamically to any RGB value.

But it looks like ImageButton only has a "setBackgroundTint" method that takes a ColorStateList which only takes color resource.

Is there anyway for me to use Color.rgb() to set the color for my image?

Comment: `ColorStateList` has the static method [`valueOf(int color)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html#valueOf(int)) which returns a `ColorStateList` of a single color.

Comment: i think valueOf should be a color resource? how can a color ever be an int?

Comment: "i think valueOf should be a color resource?" - Nope, just a color value. "how can a color ever be an int?" - What do you think `Color.rgb()` returns?

Comment: @MikeM. I think you are right! lol I didn't realize they represent color with just an Int. I will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little confusing, since there's a `Color` class, but that doesn't really represent a color value. Cool, I'll move that to an answer, then. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColorStateList` class has the static method [`valueOf(int color)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html#valueOf(int)) that you can use with `Color.rgb()` to get a `ColorStateList` of a single color. For example:

```
ColorStateList tint = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(255, 0, 255));
imageView.setBackgroundTintList(tint);
```